# react-final-form - wizard form access values from parent

Tags: wizard, react-final-form

How to access to the form values object in a parent component when i'm using wizard form ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-kare-dbxp7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<FormSpy subscription={{ values: true }}>
  {({ values }) => <pre>{JSON.stringify(values)}</pre>}
</FormSpy>
```

It will only show you the values for the current page.

[image: Edit optimistic-mahavira-betj2]